Windows Server Backup Catalog
I'm using Macrium Reflect to do a monthly system image of our main server OS volume.  I am using Windows Server Backup to do a daily backup of the rest of our data.
If the system image is for say 2 weeks old and the server crashes, I then restore, what about the backups from the last 2 weeks?  Would they not show up for recovery due to there not being catalog files from that time frame?  Where are the catalog files located at? Is the catalog on the server, or where the backup is stored? I can't seem to find a good answer on this.

As you state, the monthly Macrium Reflect images will have a Windows Server Backup catalog that is up to a month out-of-date.
After restoring the server's drive from a Macrium Reflect image, you can use the command wbadmin to restore the current catalog if the catalog has been copied to another drive.
However, if the catalog is missing or damaged, then manually search for the latest Virtual Hard Disk (VHDX) file in the location that stores the backup data and mount it. The data can be restored directly from that VHDX, without need of the catalog.
Caveat
Windows Server Backup uses Volume Shadow Copy Service (VSS). There might be an issue restoring VSS data backup to a drive restored from an earlier image. Test the full backup and restore procedure! Using a spare drive, restore a month-old Macrium Reflect image, and then try restoring the more recent Windows Server Backup. [At a firm for which I worked, daily backups were made. On the day that one was needed, it was found that none of the backups could be restored!]
